# local variable reference error despite not using global and proper assignment

Tags: python

I don't usually code in python. I have class method get_review which accepts review id and returns the review from db. I don't have any globals, the variable is first assigned and then it is referenced.

here is the code for that method.

```
class review:

    def __init__(self, db, id_=None, product_id=None, rating = None, user_id = None, comment = None ):
        self.db = db

        if id_ is None:
            if not isinstance(rating, (long, int)) and (rating > 5 or rating < 0) : 
                raise Exception(notifs.errors.invalid_rating)

            self.product = product(db, product_id)
            self.rating = rating
            self.user_id = user_id
            self.comment = comment
        elif id_ is not None:
            r = self.get_review(id_)
            if r is not False:
                self.product = product(db, r[0])
                self.user_id = r[1]
                self.rating = r[2] 
                self.comment = r[3]
                self.id = id_
            else:
                raise Exception(notifs.errors.invalid_arguments)

    def get_review(self, id_):
        query = """SELECT * FROM review where id = ? """

        rv = self.db.select(query, [id_])
        if (not rv):
            return False
        else:
            return rv.pop()

    def set_review(self):
        query = """INSERT INTO review(pid, uid, rating, comment) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"""

        params = [self.product.id, self.user_id, self.rating, self.comment]
        review_id = self.db.insert(query, params)
        if (review_id is False):
            raise Exception(notifs.errors.invalid_review)
        self.id = review_id
```

The error I am getting is:

`if (not rv):
NameError: global name 'rv' is not defined`

Comment: I think we are going to need a [mcve].  The code you have posted looks fine.  It would help if your minimal example doesn't involve a database (but it may be the database which is causing the problem).  What happens if you run the code in the interactive python interpreter?  What happens if you print r before the line in error.  Is this your actual code, or is `r` actually `veryLongNameWihtATypoInTheMiddleSomewhere`?

Comment: are you checking whether r is empty with this `(len(r) is 0 or r is False )`?

Comment: @MartinBonner am as a matter of fact running it in python console for now. 'r' was actually review and I later changed it to see if it has any impact. The code works fine if I just return the `self.db.select(query,[id_])` which makes me think I am missing something in the if condition.

Comment: @MedAli the condition earlier was `(r is False or len(r) is 0)` I changed it to see if that changes anything. It didn't. Yes because the db.select can either return False or an empty array. (additionally raise an exception which I am catching elsewhere)

Comment: an empty list is equivalent to false in python, so you just need to replace this `if (len(r) is 0 or r is False ):`with this `if not r:`

Comment: @MedAli That's good to know but it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AzeemAkhter which problem that isn't solved?

Comment: Actually, `len(r) is 0` is deeply suspicious.  `is` tests object identity, not value equality.  It wouldn't surprise me if `i = 1; if (i-i) is 0: print("Zero!");` didn't print anything.  You need `len(r) == 0`.  (But having said that, I wouldn't expect it to provoke this error.)

Comment: @MedAli the actual problem after changing it to `if not r:` still says `r` is referenced before assignment.

Comment: @MartinBonner Indeed it doesn't. I removed `is` altogether and still have the same problem.

Comment: Which database and python version are you using?

Comment: @MedAli python 2.7 and sqlite3. The db methods are working fine with other classes or on its own so I don't suspect it to be the problem.

Comment: @MartinBonner I have updated the question with the complete class definition.

Comment: @AzeemAkhter I suppose the error is now with `rv`, right? Can you please update the error message that you are seeing? I didn't see the previous version of the question and it is confusing.

Comment: @jdehesa I have updated it. Surprisingly the error has changed too. now it says `global name 'rv' is not defined`

Comment: That is neither Minimal (you can hard-code fixed values for nearly all of those variables, nor Complete (you don't show the calls).

Comment: @MartinBonner I will update it again in a minute.

Comment: @MartinBonner Ok so in the process of creating the mcve I ended up solving the problem. It was actually the bad indentation(mixed spaces and tabs) which took the get_review function out of the class.

I don't know what to do with the question now. Should I delete it or let it be?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: "in the process of creating the mcve I ended up solving the problem." That is a VERY common experience.  In fact, it is one of the reasons we demand an MCVE.  I suggest you self answer the question.  It is just possible that some other poor schmuck with the same problem will get the same error, google it, and hit this question (and SO is about creating a searchable database of questions and their answers).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved while creating the MCVE. There was nothing wrong in the code itself and the problem was mixed tab and space indentation which took the `get_review` method out of the scope of the class `review`

**Lesson Learned: Always create the MCVE before posting a question on SO.**